# PHP/MySQL: Massive SQL query or several smaller queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database design here that looks this in simplified version:

Table `building`:

- id
- attribute1
- attribute2

Data in there is like:

- (1, 1, 1)
- (2, 1, 2)
- (3, 5, 4)

And the tables, `attribute1_values` and `attribute2_values`, structured as:

- id
- value

Which contains information like:

- (1, "Textual description of option 1")
- (2, "Textual description of option 2")
- ...
- (6, "Textual description of option 6")

I am unsure whether this is the best setup or not, but it is done as such per requirements of my project manager. It definitely has some truth in it as you can modify the text easily now without messing op the id's.

However now I have come to a page where I need to list the attributes, so how do I go about there? I see two major options:

1) Make one big query which gathers all values from `building` and at the same time picks the correct textual representation from the `attribute{x}_values` table.

2) Make a small query that gathers all values from the `building` table. Then after that get the textual representation of each attribute one at a time.

What is the best option to pick? Is option 1 even faster as option 2 at all? If so, is it worth the extra trouble concerning maintenance?

Comment: A single database query is generally a lot more efficient than multiple queries, and should be less code as well

Comment: @MarkBaker There can be up to 20 attributes though... Any reason to have a different opinion then?

Comment: The more attributes, the more reason to use a single query rather than 20 individual queries - time costs to execute a query are a lot higher than the time costs to loop through a resultset, so 20 queries that each return 1 result is almost inevitably a lot slower than 1 query that returns 20 results

Comment: Why not JOIN? The databases engines are optimised for this.

Comment: Why not measure? If one table changes frequently, and others don't, small queries might be a good choice as they'll hit the query cache more often. You should code both, generate 1,000,000 rows or so, write some code to randomly update rows on tables that you think will change and benchmark.

Comment: I also agree than 1 query is more efficient and is worth a bit of extra trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion would be to create a view on the server with only the data you need and query from that.  That would keep the work on the server end, and you can pull just what you need each time.

Comment: How would making a view be any different from writing it all in 1 query from an efficiency standpoint?

Comment: Gather the data into a view and then query off of that so you don't find yourself writing long queries full of joins every time you need to pull the data.  It's more code efficient than anything.  It also gives him a more presentable way of viewing the data in the database since it is in multiple tables.  I can't really imagine why you wouldn't want a view, unless you have a factor in mind that I'm not considering.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of rows in attributes table, then I suggest to fetch them first, fetch all of them! store them into some array using id as index key in array.

Then you can proceed with building data, now you just have to use respective array to look for attribute value

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something in-between.  Parse the result from the first table in php, and figure out how many attributes you need to select from each attribute[x]_values table.

You can then select attributes in bulk using one query per table, rather than one query per attribute, or one query per building.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP solution:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM building";
$result = mysqli_query(connection,$query);
$query = "SELECT * FROM attribute1_values";
$result2 = mysqli_query(connection,$query);
$query = "SELECT * FROM attribute2_values";
$result3 = mysqli_query(connection,$query);
$n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($i = 1; $n <= $i; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    mysqli_data_seek($result2,$row['attribute1']-1);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    $row2['value'] //Use this as the value for attribute one of this object.
    mysqli_data_seek($result3,$row['attribute2']-1);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
    $row3['value'] //Use this as the value for attribute one of this object.
}
```

Keep in mind that this solution requires that the tables attribute1_values and attribute2_values start at 1 and increase by 1 every single row.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle / Postgres / MySql DBA here:

Running a query many times has quite a bit of overhead. There are multiple round trips to the db, and if it's on a remote server, this can add up. The DB will likely have to parse the same query multiple times in MySql which will be terribly inefficient if there are tons of rows. Now, one thing that your PHP method (multiple queries) has as an advantage is that it'll use less memory as it'll release the results as they're no longer needed (if you run the query as a nested loop that is, but if you query all the results up front, you'll have a lot of memory overhead, depending on the table sizes).

The optimal result would be to run it as 1 query, and fetch the results 1 at a time, displaying each one as needed and discarding it, which can reek havoc with MVC frameworks unless you're either comfortable running model code in your view, or run small view fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic and i think that to get an answer you should give more hints to how this page will look like and how big the dataset is.
You will get all the buildings with theyr attributes or just one at time?
Cause  your data structure look like very simple and anything more than a raspberrypi can handle it very good.

If you need one record at time you don't need any special technique, just JOIN the tables.
If you need to list all buildings and you want to save db time you have to measure your data.
If you have more attribute than buildings you have to choose one way, if you have 8 attributes and 2000 buildings you can think of  caching attributes in an array with a select for each table and then just print them using the array. I don't think you will see any speed drop or improvement with so simple tables on a modern computer.

```
$att1[1]='description1'
$att1[2]='description2'
....
```

Answer (score -1):

Never do one at a time queries, try to combine them into a single one.

MySQL will cache your query and it will run much faster. PhP loops are faster than doing many  requests to the database.

The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html